# should I set the state in compoenentDidMount?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have AppContainer, which is other screen is render in:

```
class AppContainer extends Component {

state= {
  Home: false
}

renderFooterTab = () => {
    return this.footerItems.map((tabBarItem, index) => {
      return (
        <GlobalFooterTab
          key={index}
          title={tabBarItem.title}
          selected={tabBarItem.selected}
        />
      );
    });
  };

render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <StatusBar />
        {this.renderHeader(this.props)}
        <Content {...this.props} contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
          {this.props.children}
        </Content>
        {this.renderFooter(this.props)}
      </Container>
    );

footerItems = [
    {
      screen: 'home',
      title: 'Home,
      selected: this.state.isHome
    }...
]
}
```

Using react navigation, I can get the screne  using  `this.props.navigation.state;`

How can I change the state when I get the `this.props.navigation.state` value and `NOT render the page twice`?

---

I did this, the state is change, but the tab is not render:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      isHome: false
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is really no need to use `state` for this and it's discouraged by the [React team](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) (Search for "Avoid copying props into state").  Instead, just continue to use the props.

```
const { routeName } = this.props.navigation.state;

footerItems = [
  {
    screen: 'home',
    title: 'Home,
    selected: routeName === 'Home'
  }...
]
```

If you **really** want to, you can use "[derived state](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html)" like this:

```
const { routeName } = this.props.navigation.state;
const isHome = routeName === 'Home';

...

footerItems = [
  {
    screen: 'home',
    title: 'Home,
    selected: isHome
  }...
]
```